# Malware scans for Jupyer Notebook uploads?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virus-scanning

For a project I am working on we need to allow users to upload Notebook files. What are some of the ways that we can use to make sure that the uploaded Notebook file doesn't include a malicious payload? Although they are just json files can the attacker embed malicious codes on them ?